# JMS Deserializing is not working with exclusion policy

Tags: php, symfony, deserialization, jms-serializer

I'm working on a **Symfony** application, and I have a User entity :

```
/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="user")
* @Serializer\ExclusionPolicy("all")
*/
class User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     *
     * @Serializer\Expose()
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string $email
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Email()
     * @Serializer\Expose()
     */
    private $email;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $password;
}
```

I'm trying to deserialize the request payload to my entity like so :

```
$data = $this->request->request->all();
$jsonContent = $this->serializer->serialize($data, 'json'); // serializing goes fine
dump($jsonContent);
{
     "email":"John.Doe@domain.com",
     "password":"123"
}
$object = $this->serializer->deserialize($jsonContent, User::class, 'json'); 
dump($object); // I'm getting null values
AppBundle\Entity\User {
  -id: null
  -email: null
  -password: null
}
```

so when I try to validate my object using the validator :

`$errors = $this->validator->validate($object);`

the validation fails with this response :

```
{
  "errors" : 
  {
     "email": "This value should not be blank.",
     "password": "This value should not be blank."
  }
}
```

but, when I remove this line `@Serializer\ExclusionPolicy("all")` everything works fine.

I'm using :

- Symfony 3.4
- jms/serializer-bundle 2.3

How can I solve this issue ?

Comment: Can you post a dump of the class metadata returned in \JMS\Serializer\Metadata\Driver\AnnotationDriver::loadMetadataForClass

Comment: how can I get that ? @AlexandruCosoi

Comment: just go into the class and before return $classMetadata; put a error_log((json_encode($classMetadata)). and check the error_log after to get the json metadata

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do that would be to use form like this:

UserType

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('email')
            ->add('password')
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\User'
        ));
    }
}
?>
```

In your controller you can have :

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/api/users", name="api_users_post_something")
     * @Method("POST")
     */
    public function postSomethingAction(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $this->serializer->deserialize($request->getContent(), 'array', 'json');
        $user = new User();
        $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user, ['csrf_protection' => false]); // disable csrf_protection if you are making api
        $form->submit($data);

        if(!($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())) {
            // Send form errors
        }

        // Persist and flush or do what you want to do
    }
}
?>
```

This is just an attempt of example by processing with form and using form validation.
I hope that that will be able to help you.